# PHP Websocket Reading Headers

Tags: php, http, websocket, header, handshake

**I'm trying to work with PHP sockets**

```
$msgsock = socket_accept($socket) or die('Could not accept incoming connection');

$msg = socket_read($msgsock, 2048) or die('Could not read input');

echo $msg;
```

**Outputs a string:**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost Connection: Upgrade Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84 Upgrade: websocket
```

**Does PHP have a convenient way to get data from this HTTP request???**

**Example:**

```
$headers = SomeConvenientMethod($msgsock);
$headers.Upgrade 
   //Output should be 'websocket'
$headers.Host
   //Output should be 'localhost'
```

Comment: https://php.uz/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php is part of a PECL extension, but the user comments have alternative implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.